# Python Pattern Printing by accepting 5 Digit number as input

Tags: python

We were asked to write python program to read 5 digit number for example if the user entered 12345 the result should be :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I have written something like below but it's not working and appending the output to earlier digit.

```
n = '12345'
for i in range(len(n)+1):
    for j in range(i+1):
         print(n[0:j],end = "")
    print()
```

The wrong output is

```
1
112
112123
1121231234
112123123412345
```

Please help in achieving  the output in above format mentioned. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
for i in range(1, len(n) + 1):
    print(n[:i])
```

There's no need for a nested loop here.

Comment: There's no need for a loop here ;-) `print(*itertools.accumulate(n), sep='\n')` (not one written by us, at least)

Answer (score 0):

your answer  has four  errors

error 1 :
range of i should be 1 to len(n)+1 if u take zero it will print space in first line ,for avoiding that start ur range (1,len(n)+1)

error 2:
range of j should be i only cause i+1 is sending it out of range

error 3:
as u are doing slicing of string u have to pass the the j only cause u are slicing the string from one index number to other ....but u just need the letter of  that index

error 4:
in the last line u have to print("\r") so that it will go to new line

```
n = '12345'
for i in range(1,len(n)+1):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(n[j],end = "")
    print("\r"
```

output will be like this :

```html
<pre>
1
12
123
1234
12345
</pre>
```